# What is the correct way of filtering or querying the AWS RDS DBInstances based on status:Available using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-rds

I am trying to get the count of RDS DB instances from AWS Console using Python.

I am able to get the counts from AWS RDS, but I cannot get the count based on their `Status: Available`.

Here is my code:

```
client3 = boto3.client('rds', aws_access_key_id=access_key, 
aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name=region)
rds = client3.describe_db_instances().filter(query=[{'Name': 'status', 
'Values': ['available']}])  # Throws Error as filter and query are no 
 attributes
for rdsdb in rds['DBInstances']:#['DBInstanceStatus'=='available']:
  rds_count.append(rdsdb)
f.writerow(('p_rds_count', len(rds_count)))
print("rds->" + str(len(rds_count)))
```

The output:

```
 rds = client3.describe_db_instances().filter(query=[{'Name': 'status', 
 'Values': ['available']}]) AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 
 'filter'
```

How can I accomplish this?

AWS console should be like:

```
Status
available
```

Comment: Side-note: You should avoid putting credentials in your code. If credentials have been saved with the `aws configure` command, then boto3 will automatically use them.

Comment: @Joihn, Yes sure i will be putting it separately. thanks for the note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply check the status of all instances returned:

```
import boto3

rds_client = boto3.client('rds')

instances = rds_client.describe_db_instances()

available = [i['DBInstanceIdentifier'] for i in instances['DBInstances'] if i['DBInstanceStatus'] == 'available']

print len(available)
```

Comment: how can I do the same way for elbv2 with status: active what are the keywords here for load balancer as for rds we have DBInstanceStatus. ELBv2 Try:
bals = elbv2.describe_load_balancers()
for elb in bals['LoadBalancers']:
    set2 = elb['LoadBalancerName']
    elbv2_count.append(set2)
    elb2 = len(elbv2_count)
print('elbV2->'+str(len(elbv2_count)))

Comment: @dow Please create a new question rather than asking in a comment.

Comment: can you please suggest the keywords for Images
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52329817/how-to-query-images-amis-from-aws-console-based-on-their-status-available-usi