# How to Query Images AMI's from AWS Console based on their status : Available using Python boto3?

Tags: python, image, boto3, amazon-ami

I need to get the Details of Images AMI's from AWS Console based on their State: Available.

When I tried it is getting stuck and not printing any line.

Python code 1:

```
conn = boto3.resource('ec2')
image = conn.describe_images()
print(image) # prints nothing
for img in image:
  image_count.append(img)
print("img count ->" + str(len(image_count)))
#prints nothing
```

Is there any exact keywords for this Image AMI's Please correct me

Comment: @John rotenstein, can you suggest your ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important thing to realize about AMIs is that *every* AMI is provided.

If you only wish to list the AMIs belonging to your own account, use `Owners=self`:

```
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

images = ec2_client.describe_images(Owners=['self'])

available = [i['ImageId'] for i in images['Images'] if i['State'] == 'available']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @John Rotenstein, This is working exactly in a fine way. The owners= self, helped me a lot to get images owned by me. I need to know the difference between boto3.client('ec2') VS boto3.resource('ec2'). how it works

Comment: Basically the `client` version maps 1:1 to the official AWS API calls. The `resource` version is exclusive to `boto` and gives it more of an _object_ feel. The `client` version often needs lots of parsing of JSON, whereas `resource` has fields directly accessible but not always easy to view to see what's there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do your own filtering change `describe_images(Filters...)` to `describe_images()`. Note: `describe_images()` returns a lot of data. Be prepared to wait a few minutes. On my system 89,362 images for us-east-1.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')

image_count = []

response = client.describe_images(Filters=[{'Name': 'state', 'Values': ['available']}])

if 'Images' in response:
    for img in response['Images']:
        image_count.append(img)

print("img count ->" + str(len(image_count)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @John Hanley, your code works well and brings all images.